# Position of UISearchBar moving down when clicked on iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, searchbar

I have a trouble with a search bar only on iOS 10 (it works well on iOS 11) and I don't know what's going on, it's been several days I'm trying to solve this by myself without success so I hope someone here could tell me what I do wrong.
So, initially, my screen is like this

[image]

And when I click in the search bar, it goes like that

[image]
If I type text, it well displays the results under the search bar. I just don't know where this space between my search bar and the navigation bar comes from.
The results of my search is managed by an another viewcontroller declared like this.

```
let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationSearchTableViewController") as! LocationSearchTableViewController
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
```

A bit of my code, especially where I set up the search bar:

```
let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a place or address"
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.searchController = resultSearchController
            resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        } else {
            searchBar.delegate = self
            searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default
            searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
            searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .default
            navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            searchBar.isTranslucent = false
            resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            mainView.addSubview(searchBar)
        }
        definesPresentationContext = true
        resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    }
```

Comment: Have you figure out? :)

Comment: Yes, but I don't quite remember what I've done for that. Do you have the same issue? If so, I can dig a bit and see what I've changed from this code to make it work.

Comment: Yeah, but nevermind. I've decided to set hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true, so the issue is no longer there. Thanks anyway

Comment: But yeah, if you think you can quickly add an answer with the solution for other people too, you are very welcome

Comment: @aneuryzm you're right, I just posted my updated code. Funny story, in my code, I set hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation to false ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who might encounter the same issue, here is my code now and it's working.

```
    let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a place or address"
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.searchController = resultSearchController
        resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    } else {
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .default
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.barStyle = .default
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        UI_mapView.addSubview(searchBar)
    }
    definesPresentationContext = true
    let currentLocationButtonItem = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: UI_mapView)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = currentLocationButtonItem
```